# Check $BINDIR value

Tags: linux

First of all I need to apology, I have very little Unix/Linux knowledge.

I am following http://dns323.kood.org/howto:subversion to install SVN server on my DLink DNS323 device. I have successfully install Fonz Fun Plug. And I think I installed subversion-1.5.2-1.tgz as well.

According to the document I need to run svnserve.sh, in which part of the soruce code is

```
svnserve_start() {
    if [ -x "{$BINDIR}/svnserve" ]; then
        echo "Starting svnserve deamon... "
        ${BINDIR}/svnserve -d -r ${REPOSITORY}
    else
        echo "ERROR: svnserve not found or not executable"
    fi
}
```

I got `ERROR: svnserve not found or not executable` message, so it looks like to me $BINDIR is not defined well.

Anybody knows, how can I do `echo` to display the value of `$BINDIR`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this bash? Shouldn't `{$BINDIR}` be `${BINDIR}`?

Comment: I would suggest to take time to learn Linux by installing it on your main PC (laptop or desktop) computer.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $BINDIR` before the `if` statement to check whether `{$BINDIR}/svnserve` exists.

It seems that `{$BINDIR}/svnserve` is not executable. Find that file and `chmod u+x` which add executable attr to it.